# IE 11.0.9600.18538 "state":"session not created" while doing testing of polymer application with WCT

Tags: unit-testing, polymer, wct

Getting the error while running the test case for polymer application. I am not getting where I am doing wrong.

Error is:

```
IE 11.0.9600.18538       Tests failed:{  
   "state":"session not created",
   "sessionId":null,
   "hCode":613752704,
   "value":{  
      "additionalInformation":"\nDriver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver",
      "localizedMessage":"Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName 
=internet explorer, javascriptEnabled=true, version=11.0.9600.18538, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]\nBuild info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'\nSystem info: host: 'HIGURL62680', ip: '10.97.6.223', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'a 
md64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'\nDriver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver",
      "supportUrl":null,
      "systemInformation":"System info: host: 'HIGURL62680', ip: '10.97.6.223', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'",
      "cause":null,
      "stackTrace":[  
         {  
            "fileName":"ProtocolHandshake.java",
            "nativeMethod":false,
            "methodName":"createSession",
            "className":"org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake",
            "hCode":-960127865,
            "lineNumber":91,
            "class":"java.lang.StackTraceElement"
         }
      ],
      "suppressed":[  

      ],
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.